# Filter model on multiple fields inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a model $scope.cases that contains a list of cases in this format:

```
{
    "DailyEventCaseID": 0,
    "LocID": "LA ",
    "CourtRoom": "9",
    "CaseID": 0,
    "EventDate": "2015-09-14T00:00:00",
    "DisplayTime": "08:30 am",
    "SortTime": "08:30",
    "SeqNumber": null,
    "StatusID": null,
    "Case": {
      "CaseID": 0,
      "CaseNumber": "BP120669",
      "DivisionCode": "PR",
      "District": "LA ",
      "CaseTitle": "MESCHUK, JOHN & WALBURGA - TRUST (5/10/1989)"
    },
    "Status": null,
    "Events": [
      {
        "EventID": 0,
        "DailyEventCaseID": 0,
        "EntityNumber": "0051",
        "EventName": "INSTRUCTIONS",
        "DailyEventCase": null
      },
      {
        "EventID": 0,
        "DailyEventCaseID": 0,
        "EntityNumber": "0052",
        "EventName": "INSTRUCTIONS",
        "DailyEventCase": null
      },
      {
        "EventID": 0,
        "DailyEventCaseID": 0,
        "EntityNumber": "0053",
        "EventName": "AMENDED-REMOVAL OF TRUSTEE",
        "DailyEventCase": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

There are multiple records like this inside the model. Unfortunately the service that saves both the `SeqNumber` and the `Status` was written in a way that requires me to return the entire object so that it can be saved in a database table. What I am doing is creating a function that accepts 3 parameters: CaseID, CaseNum, and MyEventDate. I then want to filter the model based on the values of CaseNum, and MyEventDate (which will get me down to one object). This way I can pass the object to the service and have the save happen.

I have tried the following:

```
$scope.filteredCase = $filter('custom')($scope.cases, { "Case.CaseNumber": CaseNum, "EventDate": MyEventDate });
```

I have injected the filter service:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'HoldState', '$filter', 
  function ($scope, $http, HoldState, $filter) {
```

However, I am unable to do this because when I include "Case.CaseNumber" in the search criteria I get no results and when I remove it I get the results that match "EventDate" as requested. Unfortunately, CaseNumber is buried a level deeper. How do I reference it properly in the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `$filter` there is a `$` wildcard you can use to match properties that are deeper than first level.

Personally I find it easier to write my own for cases like this using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
$scope.filteredCase = $scope.cases.filter(function(case){
    var isCaseMatch = CaseNum ? Case.CaseNumber === CaseNum : true,
        isDateMatch = MyEventDate ? case.EventDate === MyEventDate : true;      
   return isCaseMatch  && isDateMatch ;    
});
```

I am making assumption that `MyEventDate` is string...adjust accordingly.
This is also absolute matching using `===`. For partial matching use `indexOf()`

Many people will also use a library like lodash or underscore for these sorts of operations

Comment: never really used it...is shown in docs though and doesn't appear to be able to target specific property

Comment: This answer was correct but all I did was this:`$scope.filteredCase = $filter('custom')($scope.cases, { $: CaseNum, "EventDate": MyEventDate })`

Comment: still more efficient to use own filter since the `$` has to go through each and every property at all levels. It does add convenience though

Comment: Yes, but when there are going to be a max of 50 or so records and the case number is only in one field, it is pretty much immediate.

Comment: Oh, you are totally correct. I actually saved the code you provided for future use in the application. We are going to have to filter documents based on search entries form the user and it is going to come in handy. That's why I marked you as the correct answer. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!